# example of ring or algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Question:

A = {B ⊆ $\mathbb{R}$ | ∃s ≥ 0, sodass B ⊆ [−s, s]}

C = {C ⊆ $\Omega$ | C finite}

D = {D ⊆ $\Omega$ | D countable}

with $\Omega$ is uncountable. I have to decide which is ring, $\sigma$-ring, algebra, $\sigma$-algebra.

My Answer so far:

for A: 
i) A $\neq$ ∅

ii) M,N $\in$ A,then M ∪ N ∈ A

iii) M,N ∈ A,then M \ N ∈ A

i can proof for these 3 items. So A is a ring

iv) R $\subseteq$ A

I proof this one using contradiction. Suppose n=[a,b] $\subseteq$ R but n $\nsubseteq$ A. It means whether a or b is not in A. suppose b is not in A and b > 0, but it's clear that b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. So there is a set A, which contains b. And thats a contradiciton. therefore A is also an algebra.

v) $B_k$ ∈ A, k ∈ N => I think union of $B_k$ is also in A

So A is a $\sigma$-algebra

for C: (i) - (iii) works fine in C. But I think C is not a algebra. Counterexample: $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and C = [3,4]. We know that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and C is finite. Take example 5, clearly 5 is not in B but 5 is in $\mathbb{R}$. C is a not $\sigma$-ring, because union of finite sets is not always finite. Example union of {n} for n $\in \mathbb{N}$

for D: (i)-(iii) is fine. D is not a algebra. Counterexample: $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and D = $\mathbb{Q}$. see $\sqrt{2}$. D is $\sigma$-ring, because union of countable is also countable.